# Setting up Google Cloud Speech API to transcribe interviews

Tags: speech-to-text, transcription, google-cloud-speech

I've got over 100 hours of audio associated with video interviews for a documentary that need to be transcribed to text - hopefully with some kind of timecode markers every 30 seconds or so so the video can easily be matched up to the text in the edit suite.

The files are BWAV 24 bit 96khz and WAV 16 bit 48khz and last anywhere from 20 minutes to 2 hours.

What kind of resources need to be setup in a VM to do this kind of activity? I suspect it will be rather compute intensive so the VM might need 32 cores and a fair amount of memory, but there is no need for realtime response so it is ok if priorities are low and it takes several hours to process a file. My budget is miniscule - $300 is about the most we can afford for all the files (which is one reason we aren't sending these files out to a transcription service at $75+/hour).

I've already got a Cloud Platform account but have never used it. There is no point in my floundering around if someone has already done something similar and can give me some help.

Comment: You'd better use some service specifically designed for transcription of long files. For example, Speechmatics

Comment: Thanks, seems to be way simpler than having to code.

Comment: It worked. Have already processed 2 hours of interviews. Of course it isn't perfect, but transcriptions never are. It's close enough that it is really helpful and the cost is 6p (uk) per minute so it won't break the bank.

Comment: Hi @rieka what did you use that worked for transcribing interviews (which has multi-speakers I assume)? The Google API or Speechmatics?? Thanks!